# Osimidi Stage and Beringer BCF2000 with Ubuntustudio

Tags: remote

I'm new to Ubuntustudio and I don't know much about Linux. I use the last LTS version.

I use a Beringer xr18.
I control it with the X-AIR application thru a wifi router. It's working fine

I want to use my midi controller BCF2000 and Osimidi Stage to have a physical controller in top of the X-AIR app.
To do so, Osimidi Stage must see the

XR18 mixer -> Ok
The X-AIR application -> KO
The BCF2000 -> KO

My BCF2000 is in Mackie mode and I could see it somewhere in pulse.

I get osimidi Stage from osimidi web site and X-AIR from Beringer web site to.

I don't know my issue is caused by a bad application, a missing driver or settings in Ubuntustudio

If someone have the same setup any help would be appreciated.

Regards Bertrand

Comment: Please be specific with details; what exactly do you mean by *last LTS* (*a lot of users of this & other support sites often use such terms, and often mean something very different to those who are involved with the project actually know gets released*)   You're using the KDE Plasma desktop I take it (*the second-to-last LTS used Xfce so it matters you being specific*)